# Bending at "s'lach lanu"

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, bowing-kneeling

I have seen many people bow slightly when striking their chests in recitation of the [sixth *b'racha* of *sh'moneh esrei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmone_Esrai#Structure_of_the_weekday_Amidah). Is this a custom? Is there a source for it?

Anyone whom I've witnessed doing this has only given me anecdotal information as the source of the practice.

Comment: There are definitely sources for doing so during vidui, but I can't think of any for סלח לנו.

Comment: Do you know that they do it intentionally?  After seeing this question I paid attention to what I did this morning and found that I naturally bowed slightly while striking the chest.  It wasn't an intentional act but it felt natural.  So is the bow first-order choreography, or a side-effect?

Comment: @Monica Cellio - Well, only in the cases when I've asked them afterward. I am assuming based on those people intentionality in the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Piskei T'shuvos (115:2), citing Maharil,  writes that whist striking the chest during *s'lach lanu*, one should bow his head slightly forward.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old minhag. I believe that the Mishna Berura mentions it.

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE! Your answer could be improved if you could dig up and add the relevant M"B citation and quotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the source for this, but I remember learning about [*vidui*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidui) that it is a form of bowing your head in "shame", for the evil deeds.
I assume, as @jake said in a comment, that this is similar for סלח לנו.

Comment: I was assuming the same and ascribing that logic to the people I've seen doing it. I just have never seen or heard it mentioned as an actual *minhag*.